# Diablo 3 Apprentice Mode/System?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I've read about the new Apprentice Mode/System introduced in Diablo 3 Ultimate Evil Edition that was released on consoles this week and I have some questions.

I read that if a lower level friend joins my game he will be boosted up to an appropriate level for my game temporarily for the game session, which means he'll do more damage, be able to withstand more damage himself and he'll even get XP and loot tailored to his real level so that once he leaves my game he can continue to play with the shiny loot he got.

I have a couple of questions for this.

- If we're at different points in the quest line, how will this affect each person's savegame once they leave the co-op session?
- If we do it the other way around, ie. high-level character joins low-level game, will the game scale up or down?

Examples.

If I start a level 1 character and immediately joins a friend at, say, level 20, who's in the second act, and then complete a few quests in that game, and then leave, how will my own quest progress be then? Will I continue from where we left off in the co-op game, or will I start back at the beginning? If I start back at the beginning, once I get to the point we completed the quests together will those quests auto-complete (since I already did them) or will I have to do them again?

What if we do it the other way around, I start a new level 1 character and immediately my level 20 friend joins my game. Will the game session be scaled to level 1 or level 20? ie. will all the mobs, and me, be scaled up for the level 20 character, or will the mobs, and the joining player, be scaled for level 1 (meaning that the joining player will scale down)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just played last night, I was lvl 25, my buddy was lvl 5. We were going to get him past the Skeleton King, and I told him to crank up the difficulty for faster XP. I joined his game, headed into the cathedral and beat down by some unique. His game and him were scales up to match me. Worked out well. Wasn't as easy as I expected, but we both got some good XP, and the drops matched our character levels.  Sorry friends, no more rushing your lowbie friends to Act V.

Answer (score 0):

I only started to play Ultimate Evil, but I have experience with vanilla Diablo III on consoles. The below is from my vanilla experience and could possibly have changed in this edition.

If you join a player and quit on, say, Act II, then when your reload you game, you'll be in Act II on whatever quest you left off in the co-op game. That said, you can instead opt to load a different Act/quest on the main menu (Game Settings, I think it is called instead of Continue). Per character, the game keeps track of quests you've completed (solo or multiplayer). I personally have characters who I only made it solo to Act II, but has access to a few Act IV quests because I completed those with a party. So if you want to go back to Act I with your low level character, you can do it.

The apprentice mode is new, so I don't know how the party level scaling works just yet.